# Why those two expressions are not equal?

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I want to capture words that don't have the same letters next to each other. This one finds a letter and then checks if another letter next to it is not the same. This one works.

```
\b((\w)(?!(\2)))+\b
```

This one says do not match words that have the same letters next to each other, at least that's what I think it should do, but it doesn't work.

```
\b(?!((\w)\3))+\b
```

Comment: **FYI**, the second one is referencing a non-existent subpattern (in this case `\3`, it would be `\2` ..) and using the `+` quantifier outside of the lookahead is not quantifiable.

Comment: A look ahead using `(?!…)` does *not* create a capturing group, so you only have *two* capturing groups in your second expression, making the `\3` invalid.

Comment: @hwnd What do you mean non-existent subpattern?

Comment: @poke hwnd One of you should make a post, so I can accept. What is the reason behind look ahead not creating a capturing group?

Comment: @JohnSmith Lookarounds are zero-width assertions. They don't consume any characters on the string. The point of zero-width is the validation to see if a regex can or cannot be matched looking ahead or looking back from the current position, without adding them to the overall match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second pattern `\b(?!((\w)\3))+\b` is very odd

- There is no `\3` because the negative look-ahead `(?!...)` doesn't form a capture group, so you have just two groups
- If the overall pattern matches then you know the negative look-ahead *hasn't* matched, so `\1` and `\2` will never be defined
- You are asking for multiple copies of a zero-width pattern (a negative look-ahead matches a *single point* in a string)
- The negative look-ahead will never consume any characters, so there can never be any characters between the two word boundaries

It's hard to know how to "fix" this for you as I can't see the algorithm that you were trying to implement. You first pattern doesn't need the parentheses around `\2`: just `(?!\2)` is fine, and you don't capture the whole word to use after the match, which is usually a better way to go than using the whole matched string

I think I would write this

```
\b((?:(\w)(?!\2))+)\b
```